# Contar horas dentro de un día

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando obtener las horas de un día que hay en la tabla de la base de datos.
De momento solo he conseguido obtener las horas entre dos campos de la tabla:

```
SELECT DATE(hora_entrada) AS 'DIA', (time(hora_salida) - time(hora_entrada)) AS 'HRS' FROM presences
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura de la tabla es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaria saber como obtener la suma de horas de cada día, por ejemplo, del **01-06-2022**, obtener un **10**.

Comment: Buenas, podrias mostrarnos los campos `hora_salida` y `hora_entrada`???

Comment: Es difícil poder ayudar si no vemos la estructura de la tabla `presences`

Comment: @android_io recuerda que debes poner más informacion concreta a tu problema para que otros podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Hecho, he editado la pregunta, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@andyio. Se trataría de contabilizar la diferencia entre cada hora de entrada y salida, y después hacer una suma de esas diferencias agrupando por cada día.

En mi caso, te lo pongo calculado sobre segundos y después expresado en horas (dividiendo entre 3600), porque así queda abierto a lo que más se adapte a tus necesidades. Un tema a resolver que se me ocurre sería qué pasa en turnos que empiezan un día y acaban otro, y cosas así. Pero eso ya depende de la lógica del negocio.

```
SELECT DATE(hora_entrada) AS 'DIA', SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(hora_salida, hora_entrada ))) / 3600 AS 'HRS'
    FROM presences
    GROUP BY DATE(hora_entrada)
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: andyio... sí, por supuesto... agrupas por lo que quieras. En ese caso sería `GROUP BY id_trabajador` (sin poner el campo `DIA`, claro). O, si quieres, puedes sumar las horas de un trabajador cada mes o cada semana. Por ejemplo, `SELECT YEARWEEK(hora_entrada) AS 'SEMANAANHO', id_trab, [.....] GROUP BY YEARWEEK(hora_entrada), id_trab;`

Answer (score 0):

andyio, haga una prueba haver se logra exito.

***1 - Debes sumar las horas entre horas_entradas y horas_salida de cada id_trab*** 
suma_horas = TIMEDIFF(hora_salida,hora_entrada)

***2 - Obtener las horas agrupadas de por dia***

```
    SELECT DATE(hora_entrada) AS DIA,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(suma_horas))) AS total_horas 
    FROM nome_tabla
    GROUP BY DIA
    ORDER BY DIA
```

***3 - Obtener las horas agrupadas de por intervalo de dias***

```
    SELECT DATE(hora_entrada) AS DIA,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(suma_horas))) AS total_horas 
    FROM nome_tabla
    WHERE DATE(hora_entrada) BETWEEN 'fecha inicio' AND 'fecha final' 
    GROUP BY DIA
    ORDER BY DIA
```

Comment: Jose, esta consulta que propones no agrupa las horas sumando las de cada día. Sumaría todas las que cumplan un criterio, pero no te da el listado total de cada día

Comment: VFG, lo he hecho, gracias.